# How to add custom code inspection rule in Rider

Tags: rider, code-inspection

I want to add a custom inspection rule in Rider 2017.3.1, basically the same as what is possible with ReSharper (see [ReSharper Documentation here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html)). It uses the "Search with Pattern" right-click command, which is not available in Rider. Is there a different way to add custom inspection rules to Rider or something that achieves the same effect - the highlighting of problematic code?

As an example, I have the following code:

```cs
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(_ => DoSomething()).AddTo(Disposer);
```

If the `.AddTo(Disposer)` is missing, I want to highlight the code, and ideally offer a quick-fix to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Structural Search and Replace is currently not supported in Rider. You may want to track this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-11489

Comment: It's maddening that this feature exists in both ReSharper _and_ IDEA, but not Rider.